# Character segmentation of an image with overlapping parts

Tags: python, ocr, captcha

I try to segment captcha with overlapping characters, but nothing works at all.

I have read some articles concerning character segmentation and tried to implement an algorithm of summing over pixels by columns and finding local minima which should constitute to start of different character. However, the algorithm doesn't work as characters are very skewed.

Also I tried to erode away overlaps, but it ends up completely eroding significant part of text.

Here are some examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
img = cv.imread('captcha.png')
cv.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
gray = FindDividingCols(gray)
### algo for summing over pixels and finding local minima:
col_pix = np.apply_along_axis(lambda row: np.sum(row)//255, 0, img)
loc_min = np.r_[True, lst[1:] < lst[:-1]] & np.r_[lst[:-1] < lst[1:],True]
```

I would like to know what did I miss, or what other ways there exist to segment?

Answer (score 0):

if you really want and need to segment these heavily distorted letters into different character by character segmented input for the Neural Network to be detected then the best (and i think only way) is via the same Neural Network to segment them into different entity. so you would end up having 2 neural networks

1- for segmentation

2- for detection

Answer (score -1):

These captchas are deliberately distorted to make it extremely hard for OCR algorithms to read them. If it would be reasonably easy to do, the captcha would be pointless.  Thus, you probably have a problem that requires a lot of research and work to solve; I don't think Stack Overflow will readily provide an answer (and if it does, the captchas will get harder) ;)